# Цвет ссылки текущей страницы

Tags: css, button, link, href

Есть листинг (новостей), а данный момент выглядит это так:

[image: скрин1]

Вот код:

```
<div class="navigation-pages"><a href="/novosti/?cur_cc=60">1</a><a href="/novosti/?cur_cc=60&amp;curPos=6">2</a> </div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы кнопка текущей страницы была другого цвета? Пробовал active и selected, но не выходит

UPD:  netcat сам осуществляет листинг, поэтому в оригинале выглядит код вот так:

```
<div class="navigation-pages"><?= nc_browse_messages($cc_env, 3, $browse_msg) ?> </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте class="active" текущей ссылке 0_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то очень давно доводилось немного работать на коте, и если внимательно прочитать документацию, то там должно быть что то вроде $browse_msg['active'] = "%PAGE", и вот если "%PAGE" заменить на "`<span class="active">%PAGE</span>`" и применить к нему стили, то все будет замечательно!

Comment: В нынешней версии это выглядит вот так: $browse_msg['active'] = "\n<a href=%URL>%PAGE</a>";  и почему-то никаких манипуляций с этим не принимает, не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: Получилось! В синтаксисе ошибся, в итоге нужно как вы и сказали вот так: $browse_msg['active'] = "\n<a href=%URL><span class='active'>%PAGE</span></a>"; 
Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: <a> скорее всего лишняя, так как вы находитесь уже на данной cтранице </a>